# basic math not returning correct answers

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to make an LCD display the percentage of moisture using a soil moisture sensor and when I use a basic math line of code such as:

```
double dryPercentage = (value / 1023) * 100;
```

I get a wrong value.  When I leave it dry, it returns 100, like it should, but when I put it into water it says something around 50.  The value of the sensor when I put it into water is in the 200's so the variable dryPercentage should return something in the 20%.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the rounding or type of variable. Here is my full code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>  

int Contrast=20;
int sensor = 0;
 LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);   

void setup(){ 
  analogWrite(6,Contrast);
  pinMode(sensor, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}  
void loop(){  
  int value = analogRead(sensor);
  double dryPercentage = (value / 1023) * 100;
  int moistPercentage = 100 - dryPercentage;

  Serial.print("Input: ");
  Serial.print(value);
  Serial.print("--");
  Serial.print("Dryness: ");
  Serial.println(dryPercentage);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Hi");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("-Stuart");
}
```

Comment: What is `a wrong value`?  What value do you get?

Comment: Obvious question: what does `analogRead(sensor)` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the type definitions should be like

```
float value = analogRead(sensor);
float dryPercentage = (value / 1023.0) * 100.0;
float moistPercentage = 100.0 - dryPercentage;
```

If you want the rounded off final value

```
float value = analogRead(sensor);
int dryPercentage = (value / 1023.0) * 100.0;
int moistPercentage = 100.0 - dryPercentage;
```